# Entity Framework incorrectly saving an entity when I never added it to the Context

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

I'm using Entity Framework in .NET 4.0. I have a `Subscription` entity, which has many `CFile` entities. I create a new `CFile` entity, but never actually call `AddObject` on it. Later on I try to save the `Subscription` entity that is related to it and EF tries to save the `CFile` instance, which I never intended!

Simplified code:

```
var subscription = new Subscription();
Context.Subscription.AddObject(subscription);
Context.SaveChanges();

var cfile = new CFile() { Subscription = subscription };
if (SomeChecksPass(cfile))
{
    Context.CFiles.AddObject(cfile);
}
else
{
    // No AddObject!
}

subscription.SomeProperty = "changed";
Context.SaveChanges(); // Saves cfile as well, even if I don't want to!
```

I understand why it's happening, but how do I get it to *not* do this? This creates a rather subtle and obscure bug (the real code is obviously much more complex). I want it to only save entities that I explicitly passed to `AddObject`.

I also know of a workaround: call `Detach` on the entity that I don't want saved. It's not a good workaround, however, because I have to make sure I call Detach in every possible code path where `cfile` is not saved (and in some code paths it is saved), so it has to be called after that decision is made, but before anything else is saved. This is very brittle and I really don't want to rely on it.

**Edit:** `cfile` is created because I do want to save it *most* of the time, but if some validation fails or some error occurs then I don't. I still want to save some changes to the `subscription` object, though.

Comment: are you by any chance using self-tracking entities? or are you using out-of-the-box (code gen) EF4? im guessing your using STE, and since your newing up a CFile (which is tracked), EF is adding it to the graph. Try moving that `new CFile()` to outside your `using` statement (if your using one).

Comment: No, they are not self-tracking entities and I'm not using a `using` statement. (Which object would I enclose in `using`? I'm still new to EF.)

Comment: Normally you would enclose the context object in a using statement.

Comment: I realize that this is a simplified example, but a little more info on what you are trying to achieve by creating `cfile` could help. Just wondering, why create the object (as part of the entity graph) if you aren't saving it in the DB. As for EF behavior, it's exactly what one would expect in this situation, and I would be surprised if it acted differently. That said, you do need a hack or workaround to induce specific behavior. One way to do it is to `Detach` the object, another might be to change the state in the `ObjectStateManager`.

Comment: How about if you call `Detach` where you create the `CFile` and then it will get saved only where you currently have code to save it?

Comment: Having the same problem and trying to figure out what is going on. I just new something and its added to the context.

Answer (score 1):

Try exposing the foreign key in your EDMX (if not already there) and do something like this instead:-

```
var cfile = new CFile() { SubscriptionId = subscription.Id };
```

That should be enough to prevent the object graph from forming.

You might need to call Refresh on the subscription object after creating it (depends on how your IDs are being generated - most will get updated automatically when you SaveChanges()).

Answer (score 1):

You do not directly control what entities to save in Entity Framework, it saves what it thinks it should, it works with associated Object Graphs.  You can put some logic in ObjectContext.SaveChanges override using ObjectStateManager but this is pretty ugly.

If you need more control on what to save and when, maybe it is better to use some other pattern like Repository | ActiveRecord where you have better control on separate entities. Or you will often find yourself in situations you described.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using:

```
List<Ey> eys = dc.Context.Ey.ToList();
eys = eys .Where(h => h.Employee == myEmployee).ToList();
Ey esh;
for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++)
{
EmployeeSkillHistory duplicate = histories.Where(h => h.Sl == esh.Sl).FirstOrDefault();
   if (duplicate == null)
      { dc.Context.Ey.AddObject(esh); } else { dc.Context.Ey.DeleteObject(esh); }
dc.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Before using

```
else { dc.Context.Ey.DeleteObject(esh); }
```

Duplicates were saved in my database